# Using duplicity with gzip max compression but without encryption

Tags: backup, duplicity

I would like to use `duplicity` in order to perform local back-up of one USB external HD (let's call it `hd1`) to another USB external HD (let's call it `hd2`).

I already use `deja-dup` (which is based on `duplicity`) to back-up my home dir to `hd2`. I have noticed that `deja-dup` creates `sigtar.gz` files which (according to the `file` command) are `gzip` compressed (to the maximum level), non-GPG-encrypted files. This seems like a good trade-off (saving disk space without wasting time to encrypt files which is not needed in my case).

Apparently, playing with both compression and encryption at the same time with `duplicity` can be a bit tricky.

Does any know how to reproduce this setting (max compression, no encryption) with `duplicity`?

Answer (score 11):

After a more careful reading of the man page, I have found the `--no-encryption` which according to the man page: "Do not use GnuPG to encrypt files on remote system. Instead just write gzipped volumes.". That seems exactly what is needed.